# Paypal IPN and PHP: handle the order before and after Paypal operations

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have already done a small e-commerce with Paypal and it works, but I feel like it is done wrongly.

Because the page that handles the IPN response from Paypal can't read `$_SESSION` variables, before the user submits the form and is redirected to Paypal, I get all the cart items and store them in a table in the database and also I register a new order with the user information but with the status `0` ( not completed ).

Then, after the user pays and I get the IPN response, I check if the status is completed, check if the amount paid is correct, currency and the usual checks to make sure the payment is successful.

The problem with this approach is that if the user once redirected to Paypal, decide to leave/close the browser/Paypal tab, I will have a failed order registered in the database and I can't delete it but manually.

How can I handle this kind of situation, and is it correct to register the order/cart before the user pays ?

Thank you and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the transaction occurs rely on the IPN messages. Depending on which api you are using you have several way to customize the IPN message with useful information for you, ie:

- using paypal custom field
- define dynamically the IPN url with extra parameter ie www.yoursite.com/ipn?myvar=myval

That way you can have a hook between the payment and the actual user in your application.
Obiusly the php session attributes of the user is not available when the http post comes from paypal.